# How to use dplyr in R to both eliminate a row and rename a factor variable

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, recode

I'm converting some pdfs tables to data frames involving data from US states, and one of the tables has a hick-up in it where District of Colombia is broken up into two lines.  Here's a glimpse of the data

```
$ State <fct> Alabama, Alaska, Arkansas, Arizona, California, Colorado, Connecticut, District of, Columbia, Delaw…
$ Any   <fct> "1,133", "311", "591", "1,080", "3,698", "910", "643", "", "69", "32", "3,113", "1,759", "34", "876"…
$ DD    <fct> "47,421", "3,317", "41,962", "67,185", "212,800", "37,444", "9,886", "", "34,841", "2,183", "101,41"…
$ MG    <fct> "15,653", "1,617", "4,827", "16,879", "28,774", "6,040", "22,023", "", "4,278", "569", "29,128", "2"…
$ Sil   <fct> "8,550", "2,085", "7,218", "15,860", "7,303", "6,475", "5,170", "", "160", "302", "28,312", "29,259"…
$ SBR   <fct> "1,327", "508", "1,091", "5,492", "3,738", "2,217", "1,068", "", "440", "94", "7,432", "3,563", "55"…
$ SBS   <fct> "2,075", "1,101", "1,017", "1,851", "12,166", "1,389", "960", "", "1,048", "507", "6,125", "9,422",…
$ Total <fct> "76,159", "8,939", "56,706", "108,347", "268,479", "54,475", "39,750", "", "40,836", "3,687", "175",…
```

I'm trying to find a way to use dplyr to both eliminate the empty row with the State "District of" and rename the "Colombia" cell in the State column to "District of Colombia

I was trying

```
data_table %>%
  filter(as.character(State) != "District of")
```

to filter out the empty column, but that isn't working

My attempt to recode the State column was

```
  atf_data_table %>% mutate(State = recode_factor(State, `Colombia` = "District of Colombia"))
```

but that hasn't bore fruit either.

edit: Attached is the dput of a section of the data

```
structure(list(State = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
10L, 7L), .Label = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", 
"California", "Colorado", "Columbia", "Connecticut", "Delaware", 
"District of", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", 
"Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", 
"Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", 
"Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", 
"New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", 
"Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", 
"South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", 
"Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", 
"Wyoming"), class = "factor"), Any = structure(c(6L, 24L, 38L, 
4L, 23L, 50L, 40L, 1L, 44L), .Label = c("", "1,019", "1,061", 
"1,080", "1,110", "1,133", "1,330", "1,430", "1,487", "1,502", 
"1,726", "1,759", "1,776", "199", "2,012", "2,043", "2,514", 
"2,633", "221", "277", "286", "3,113", "3,698", "311", "32", 
"34", "344", "403", "404", "410", "42", "425", "430", "431", 
"517", "570", "588", "591", "6,169", "643", "670", "674", "679", 
"69", "717", "747", "820", "837", "876", "910", "933", "958"), class = "factor"), 
    DD = structure(c(41L, 26L, 38L, 47L, 21L, 36L, 52L, 1L, 33L
    ), .Label = c("", "1,605", "101,418", "102,723", "11,737", 
    "12,878", "13,004", "13,960", "14,049", "148,700", "159,805", 
    "161,841", "17,492", "19,379", "2,183", "2,216", "2,517", 
    "2,710", "2,852", "21,221", "212,800", "22,239", "24,986", 
    "25,316", "26,358", "3,317", "3,352", "3,459", "30,778", 
    "32,848", "34,628", "34,693", "34,841", "35,707", "36,066", 
    "37,444", "37,700", "41,962", "44,821", "45,037", "47,421", 
    "48,026", "5,068", "5,503", "6,776", "60,764", "67,185", 
    "69,005", "71,814", "8,318", "83,363", "9,886"), class = "factor"), 
    MG = structure(c(11L, 5L, 34L, 12L, 23L, 39L, 18L, 1L, 31L
    ), .Label = c("", "1,070", "1,480", "1,495", "1,617", "1,659", 
    "1,892", "10,703", "11,234", "13,442", "15,653", "16,879", 
    "17,019", "17,384", "18,013", "2,049", "2,438", "22,023", 
    "22,081", "23,709", "24,651", "28,690", "28,774", "29,128", 
    "3,262", "3,289", "3,709", "3,805", "3,886", "30,220", "4,278", 
    "4,342", "4,664", "4,827", "429", "569", "595", "6,010", 
    "6,040", "6,076", "6,182", "6,385", "6,442", "6,555", "6,828", 
    "6,843", "6,895", "7,521", "7,972", "8,230", "9,090", "9,863"
    ), class = "factor"), Sil = structure(c(47L, 17L, 43L, 13L, 
    44L, 38L, 36L, 1L, 15L), .Label = c("", "1,071", "1,103", 
    "1,153", "1,290", "1,826", "10,407", "105", "11,964", "12,046", 
    "12,914", "15,736", "15,860", "16,735", "160", "2,022", "2,085", 
    "2,266", "2,273", "2,303", "2,325", "2,782", "2,887", "2,920", 
    "27", "28,312", "29,259", "3,368", "3,679", "301", "302", 
    "4,359", "4,416", "4,913", "47,712", "5,170", "5,857", "6,475", 
    "6,671", "619", "68", "7,024", "7,218", "7,303", "7,457", 
    "8,400", "8,550", "8,609", "9,571", "9,839", "9,841", "965"
    ), class = "factor"), SBR = structure(c(11L, 42L, 3L, 41L, 
    35L, 25L, 2L, 1L, 39L), .Label = c("", "1,068", "1,091", 
    "1,094", "1,095", "1,103", "1,174", "1,183", "1,214", "1,315", 
    "1,327", "1,370", "1,379", "1,380", "1,419", "1,420", "1,457", 
    "1,577", "1,713", "1,787", "1,864", "1,927", "106", "134", 
    "2,217", "2,343", "2,346", "2,621", "2,623", "2,842", "2,850", 
    "260", "264", "3,563", "3,738", "3,853", "343", "369", "440", 
    "497", "5,492", "508", "55", "572", "6,720", "682", "688", 
    "7,432", "700", "895", "9,271", "94"), class = "factor"), 
    SBS = structure(c(20L, 5L, 3L, 15L, 17L, 10L, 52L, 1L, 4L
    ), .Label = c("", "1,011", "1,017", "1,048", "1,101", "1,106", 
    "1,121", "1,160", "1,309", "1,389", "1,470", "1,508", "1,638", 
    "1,674", "1,851", "112", "12,166", "12,323", "175", "2,075", 
    "2,266", "2,316", "2,542", "211", "3,655", "3,771", "3,822", 
    "345", "373", "385", "398", "410", "5,538", "507", "548", 
    "59", "6,125", "6,272", "6,557", "607", "7,342", "712", "752", 
    "767", "768", "8,581", "850", "887", "9,422", "936", "94", 
    "960"), class = "factor"), Total = structure(c(47L, 49L, 
    41L, 4L, 18L, 39L, 29L, 1L, 30L), .Label = c("", "10,871", 
    "106,513", "108,347", "108,574", "11,770", "112,931", "114,110", 
    "14,742", "15,724", "17,455", "175,528", "18,376", "197,217", 
    "223,303", "258,204", "26,151", "268,479", "27,553", "29,383", 
    "3,592", "3,687", "3,803", "30,319", "36,080", "37,307", 
    "38,917", "39,389", "39,750", "40,836", "43,589", "45,530", 
    "48,340", "48,359", "48,989", "49,024", "5,581", "50,550", 
    "54,475", "55,105", "56,706", "58,964", "6,185", "65,524", 
    "69,371", "7,652", "76,159", "8,293", "8,939", "80,736", 
    "82,187", "95,060"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: please provide some sample data that can be used directly, e.g. with `dput()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really see the issue here. This code works just fine for me

```
my_data %>%
  filter(State != "District of") %>% 
  mutate(State = recode_factor(State, 
                               "Columbia" = "District of Columbia"))
```

You had a typo in "Colombia" but the filtering is fine

Comment: I must have messed up the formatting somewhere.  Clearing out the code and re-pasting it as you put it works now.  Thank you!